# Validation Message Not Displays On ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, action

I am developing my first application using Asp.Net MVC5. In my application I have single view,In which I am going to call two action. One action by using button and another by actionlink. When I call it using button it works perfectly for validation messages.

[image]

In other hand , If I click on 'Add Another'(which is action link) I want same validation, But It does not showing any validation messages. I have implemented below code for @Html.ActionLink() click event.

In Razor View -

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Add Another", "AddNew", "AgreementRegistration", new { @class = "postLink" })
```

In Controller -

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNew(User_Master usermaster, Commercial_Master commercialmaster, Property_Master propertymaster, PropertyCommercial_Master propertycommercialmaster, PropertyDetails_Master propertydetailsmaster, SecurityDeposit_Master securitydepositmaster, PropertyUser_Master propertyusermaster, UserType_Master usertypemaster)
    {
        agreementnew = new AgreementNew(usermaster, commercialmaster, propertymaster, propertycommercialmaster, propertydetailsmaster, securitydepositmaster, propertyusermaster, usertypemaster);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Some Logic
            return View("InitialView", agreementnew);
        }
        else
        {
            //Some Logic
            return View("InitialView", agreementnew);
        }
    }
```

When I checked it using debugger then it comes to above method in else block but does not showing any validation message. I want to display all the validation message when I click on ActionLink. How do I solve this problem?

[image: Snapshot When I Clicked on 'Add Another' Link]

Comment: Your "Add another"` is a link which redirects. It does not perform validation. But what would be the point - if your redirecting, your not saving the current data so the messages would be a bit meaningless.

Comment: @StephenMuecke But I am redirecting to same view. If it's not possible then how can I implement it?

Comment: Yes you are, and that creates a new instance of your model(s) and displays a new view. Its  unclear what you want to achieve and why

Comment: I want to achieve same validation on click on actionlink, So Is there any other option to implement this, Please let me know about that.

Comment: But why? Its a link which redirects. Your not saving the data the user entered (as soon as you click the link you just throw away all the values the user has entered.

Comment: If you do want to save the current form and then redirect to create a new one, then your link also needs to be a submit button.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. I have submitted my form using javascript code as suggested by numan ali  and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by clicking on action link it doesn't submit your form. Validation is only checked when your form is submitted. So use Javascript to submit your form when clicking on your action link.

First change your action link to this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Another", "AddNew", "AgreementRegistration", new { @class = "postLink", onclick="submitMyForm()" })
```

Then add following code

```
<script>
   function submitMyForm(){
   $("#yourFormID").submit();  //assign an id to your form and use that here
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly for me. Just I added Id for form and used your code to submit my form.

Comment: @SVT002, Why on earth would you not just make it a submit button (and style it to look like a link if that's what you wanted). Using javascript for this is crazy. And now you can never know which button was clicked so what is the point of 2 different buttons/links

Comment: @StephenMuecke According to requirement, I have to use same front end for multiple times when I click on add another link and I have to implement different logic in that action.

Comment: That's is what I assumed, and this code will NOT do that. You need 2 submit buttons with the same `name` attributes (say `name="button"`) and  `value` attributes (say `value="Add Another"` and `value="Save and Next"`. The in the POST method, add a parameter `sting button` which will contain either "Add Another" or "Save and Next" depending on which button you clicked (so you can _implement different logic_ based on the button)